# Set origin to 3d cursor(3d cursor became the origin)

Tags: objects, geometry, 3d-cursor, origin

I was want to change the origin to where the cursor is, I did from Object>Set origin>Origin to 3D[enter image description cursor.

But after that, The 3D became the origin and I can't change from Object>Set origin.
Here images if You didn't understand.

[image: Here is a photo for the bug]

Comment: The pivot point is set to 3D cursor, change it to individual origins. Its just on the righ of "global" in top of 3D view... I think this is the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got the answer It's really easy you just should change it to active element or individual origins.[image]